# How can I securely access and store a master security key that is being used in an active python file?

Tags: python, security

I am making a discord bot in python and it is collecting and aggregating user/server data in a text file. I planned to have the code auto-save an encrypted "json" file (a text file with json data but without the structure) will all of this data periodically with a newly generated key. The encryption functions I made are located in a separate python file from my main bot program. I have set up an encryption generator but I have no idea how to store the key for a key generator in a way that can be accessed from code in a secure way. I am the only one that needs to access this key and my python files are being hosted locally.

Currently, I am just inputting the master encryption key manually through the terminal and then setting the key variable to None so it isn't saved in the file. I know this is horrendous but the data I have stored currently is just a bunch of sample json that I was using to test my encryption, not any actual user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing a secret variable into a program, you can take a look at [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

You can access the environment variable from Python using the following code:

```py
import os
TOKEN = os.environ.get("SECRETTOKEN")
```

To set this variable in `bash`, you can prefix the command `python bot.py` with `SECRETTOKEN="VALUE"`. Following are some examples.

```sh
$ SECRETTOKEN=1234567890 python bot.py
```

```sh
$ export SECRETTOKEN=1234567890
$ python bot.py
```

To set environment variables on Windows, you can try using [these commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#DOS,_OS/2_and_Windows).

Many hosting services use environment variables as the go-to way to store secrets, such as [Heroku](http://heroku.com/). Note that they call it "Config vars"

[image: Heroku config vars screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!

Comment: If it works, please mark my answer as accepted. 